# Perl formatting array output.

Tags: arrays, perl, format

I have a small program that I am trying to format the output.
The results get loaded in to an array - I am just having trouble formating the
printing out the array into a certain format.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict ;
use warnings ;
my @first_array ;
my @second_array  ;
my @cartesian ;

while (<>) {
    my $first_input =  $_ ;
    @first_array = split(' ', $first_input) ;
    last ;
}
while (<>) {
    my $second_input = $_ ;
    @second_array = split(' ', $second_input) ;
    last ;
}


while(my $first=shift(@first_array)) {
    push(@cartesian, $first) ;
        my $second = shift(@second_array)  ;
        push(@cartesian, $second ) ;

}

print "This is the merged array: @cartesian\n" ;
```

When I enter this in, I get this:

```
$ ./double_while2.pl
1 2 3
mon tue wed
This is the merged array 1 mon 2 tue 3 wed
```

what I want to print out is :

```
"1", "mon",
"2", "tue" ,
"3", "wed",
```

or alternately:

```
1  => "mon",
2  => "tue",
3  => "wed,
```

Comment: Tip: `while (<>) { my $first_input =  $_ ; ... last ; }` is a weird way of doing `my $first_input = <>; ...`

Comment: thank you ikegami - you are the man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use hash instead.

```
for my $i(0..$#first_array){
    $hash{$first_array[$i]} = $second_array[$i];
 }
```

or else, you want format without using hashes,  try as follows

```
for  (my $i = 0; $i < $#cartesion/2; $i++) {
      my $j  = ($cartesion/2) + $i;
      print "$cartesion[$i] $cartesion[$j] \n";

   }
```

Answer (score 4):

May I suggest a hash, since you are pairing things

```
my %cartesian; 
@cartesian{ @first_array } = @second_array;

print "$_ => $cartesian{$_}\n" for sort keys %cartesian;
```

A *hash slice* is used above.  See [Slices in perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices)

The arrays that you build had better pair up just right, or there will be errors.

If the goal is to build a data structure that pairs up elements, that can probably be done directly, without arrays.  More information would help to comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

From your question and your code, I suppose that you are a lovely new 'victim' to perl ~
To merge two arrays with same lengh, I suggeest using 'map' to simplify your code:

```
my @cartesian = map {$first_array[$_], $second_array[$_]} 0..$#first_array;
```

and to format print style , you can define a subroutine to meet your different requirements:

```
sub format_my_array{
   my $array_ref = shift;
   my $sep = shift;
   print $array_ref->[$_],$sep,$array_ref->[$_+1],"\n" for grep {! ($_%2)} 0..$#$array_ref;
}
```

Now, you can try calling your subroutine:

```
format_my_array(\@cartesian, " => ");
```

or

```
format_my_array(\@cartesian, " , ");
```

Now, you get what you want~

You may have noticed that some intermediate concepts are used in this answer, don't doute , that's exactly what I'm trying to introduce you to ~

May you the great happiness in learning perl ~

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to go with Perl's strengths instead of fighting against them:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
# For say()
use 5.010;

my @first_array  = split ' ', <>;
my @second_array = split ' ', <>;

if (@first_array != @second_array) {
  die "Arrays must be the same length\n";
}

my @cartesian = map { $first_array[$_], $second_array[$_] } 0 .. $#first_array;

for (0 .. $#cartesian / 2) {
  say "$cartesian[$_*2] => $cartesian[$_*2+1]";
}
```

But, it gets much easier still if you use a hash instead of an array for your merged data.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
# For say()
use 5.010;

my @first_array  = split ' ', <>;
my @second_array = split ' ', <>;

if (@first_array != @second_array) {
  die "Arrays must be the same length\n";
}

my %cartesian;
@cartesian{@first_array} = @second_array;

for (sort keys %cartesian) {
  say "$_ => $cartesian{$_}";
}
```